# Firefox behaving differently to Safari and Chrome with jQuery variable values

Tags: jquery, firefox

I'm using a wonderful plugin [computedstyle.js](https://github.com/peol/jquery-computed-style) that gets the computed style of objects.
It allows me to manipulate the css of things you shouldn't normally be able to, like constructed images.

I'm able to take an image source which is found in a link, and change the size of the housing div and of the image itself. Usually you can only do that if you know the size of the image.

1. I construct the image
2. I size the image
3. I then size the iframe around it, based on the size of the changed image.

This works in Chrome and Safari, but of course, not Firefox, which in my opinion is fast becoming the new Internet Explorer.

The question, is there a way I can make firefox wait to notice the change and then do the resizing of the iframe?

TO see it work correctly in Chrome and Safari, go to http://syndex.me. And not correctly, Firefox.

Not a must for the question, but if you are wondering what I'm doing, I'm removing the default gallery preview of Tumblrs Photoset Post and replacing it with a single image.

```
if($(this).find('.html_photoset').length){
    $(".html_photoset").find("iframe").load(function(){
        var myFrame=$(this);                        
        $(this).contents().find('.photoset_row:not(:first-child)').each(function(){
            $(this).remove();
        })
    var psPre = $(this).contents().find('.photoset_row').find('a').attr("href");
    $(this).contents().find('.photoset_row').children(':not(:first-child)').remove();
        $(this).contents().find('.photoset_row').children(':first-child').children().remove();
        $(this).contents().find('.photoset_row').find('a').append("<img src='"+psPre+"'alt='Cover Page' />");
        $(this).contents().find('img').load(function(){
            var myCSS = $(this).getCSS(); //this is the plugin function
            var myY = myCSS.height.slice(0, - 2);
            var myX = myCSS.width.slice(0, - 2);
            $(this).closest(".photoset_row").css({height: myY});
            $(this).closest(".photoset_row").css({width: myX});
            $(this).css({maxHeight: (heightRef-0)});
            $(this).css({maxWidth: "auto"});
                    //after I've made the fixes to the image, I redo it for the iframe:
            var myCSS2 = $(this).getCSS();
            var myY2 = myCSS2.height.slice(0, - 2);
            var myX2 = myCSS2.width.slice(0, - 2);
            myFrame.height(myY2);
            myFrame.width(myX2);
            console.log(myY2);
        })                      
})
}
```

Comment: If you're becoming "used to" Chrome and Safari, I would say you're become Webkit-prone. Firefox is not a Webkit browser. Expand your horizons. `:)`

Comment: Fair enough, but this is not a webkit plugin, it's jquery. Actually i believe moz even has some internal computed style manipulators that other browsers don't, so i had to go the plugin route.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "webkit plugin" when it comes to jQuery. Either a browser supports a specific functionality or it doesn't, *and* that functionality is supported by the code/markup trying to manipulate it.

Comment: What does this getCSS function actually do?  That's not stock jQuery, and your complaint seems to be that it's not returning the data you expect, right?  Also, is the maxHeight/maxWidth stuff you do relevant?  `heightRef` is not really defined anywhere in your snippet, and `auto` is not a valid value of `max-width`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This caveat on the `.load()` [jQuery docs page](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is interesting:

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
>
> It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
>
> It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
>
> Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

So, to try and mitigate some of these, I would suggest trying to append a random query string to the end of the image href to avoid it being cached, and avoid the src being set to the same as before, etc.

i.e. change the psPre line to:

```
var psPre = $(this).contents().find('.photoset_row').find('a').attr("href") + '?' + (Math.random() * 1000000);
```

Comment: Interesting, will that really stop caching of the image? If so that's a nice little trick. It doesnt solve the problem though, but it's good to know. I think my issue is that I'm declaring a variable with very fresh data thats created in the lines directly before it, in the same function. I console logged the values of the second variable and basically it still sees the values from three lines before, so I'm pretty sure what i'm looking for is some kind of delay function or comparison tool to see first if the value has indeed changed. Once it's confirmed, it does it's thing.

Comment: Yes, if a URL is different (even if its just the query string, and that query string isn't even used by the page), the browser will think it is a new never-before-seen resource and download it, which circumvents the cache.

Comment: Also, as a general hint, try caching as much as you can in variables when working with jQuery. Any time you have a selector or function chain repeated, cache it in a variable and use the variable instead. This only runs the code once. e.g. in your code, `$(this).contents()`, `$(this).contents().find('.photoset_row')` and  even `$(this)` can all be cached in variables before they are used for the first time. This will speed up the script a bit.